# Best way to access DLLs during development

Tags: dll, development-environment

I'm creating a development environment that should be easy to install on new systems. Therefore I created library packages (OpenCV, boost, Qt etc) all placed in a single folder (environment_folder) which is accessed by an environment variable by Visual Studio projects/solutions (so for a single compiler the whole folder can be copied and only the variable has to be set).

Now to execute the binary it needs access to the DLLs of those libraries.

I typically copy all needed DLLs to the binary directory, but that's neither nice nor pratical.

Another way would be to add all the libraries' pathes to the PATH variable, but that's a lot of work to perform while/after installing the library packages, so I would like to avoid it. Additionally it is error-prone when testing new versions of libraries for example.

A third way that comes in my mind would be to copy all the DLLs to a single package_bin folder, so only a single path has to be added to the PATH variable (which is additonally relative to the environment_folder), but I don't like that idea.

Is there any better way to do it?